# Yii 2.0 Getting data from model without widget

Tags: php, yii2, yii-widgets

Can anyone give me sample of how to retrieve data from model without having to use Widget ? Because need to get data per table column and put them inside my own view (not using widget)

Controller :

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new B2CProductsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
```

View :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
            'sku',
            'name',
            'short_description',
            'long_description',
            'thumb_img:ntext',
            'large_img:ntext',
            'url_content:ntext',
             'contact_info',
             'status',
            'currency',
             'price',
            'dimension',
            'weight',
            // 'created',
            // 'modified',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

The widget above iterate through the element inside the predefined gridview,
but what I want to do instead is something like :

```
foreach($data as $ab) {
   echo $ab->id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
/* assuming $data is an ActiveDataProvider object */
$models = $data->getModels(); 

foreach($models as $model) { ... }
```

[see more here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an **ActiveDataProvider**: 
Controller:

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => MyModel::find(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('my-results-page', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
 <?php
  foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model){
            echo $model->myProperty;
        }  
 ?>
```

---

If you are using a **query**, such as this:

```
    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('this, that')
        ->from('over_there');
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $rows = $command->queryAll();
```

Then you can iterate over the result like this(assuming you passed it to the view in a variable called $dataProvider):

```
  foreach($dataProvider as $data)
  {            
   $data['myProperty'];
  }
```